# Copy several cells to paste into one single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have three different named ranges, I want the macro to copy all three, to consolidate them all (each on one separate line), and to paste them in one single cell in another worksheet.

```
 Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range, multipleRange As Range

 Set range1 = wsForm.Range("Details_Absenteisme")
 Set range2 = wsForm.Range("Boite_Infraction")
 Set range3 = wsForm.Range("Boite_Corrections")
 Set multipleRange = Union(range1, range2, range3)

 ws_operation.Range("I" & lrow_operation).Value = multipleRange
```

This only paste the value in range1.

Comment: I think you have to loop through the areas of your Union.

Comment: Each range consist of many cells or just one?

Comment: Every range is just one cell. Solution was posted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the values together and then paste them into the cell you want.

I added a space in between the different values.

```
dim copystr as string

copystr = wsForm.Range("Details_Absenteisme").value & _
" " & wsForm.Range("Boite_Infraction").value & _
" " & wsForm.Range("Boite_Corrections").value

ws_operation.Range("I" & lrow_operation).Value = copystr
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the pre mention ranges and get all the values included. This is used in case you have many cells in your range

```
Sub test()

    Dim nameRng As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim str As String

    nameRng = Split("Details_Absenteisme,Boite_Infraction,Boite_Corrections", ",")
    str = ""

    For i = LBound(nameRng) To UBound(nameRng)

        With wsForm

            For Each cell In .Range(nameRng(i))

                If str = "" Then
                    str = cell.Value
                Else
                    str = str & " " & cell.Value
                End If

            Next cell

        End With

    Next i

    MsgBox str

End Sub
```